# How to write query to insert data in two tables having foreign key relations in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have two tables in SQL Server as:

```
MobileMaster (MobileId int (PK), MobileName varchar)
```

and

```
MobileDetails (MobDetailId int (PK), MobileId int (FK), Color char, Ram int, Camera float)
```

And I have a Windows form with textboxes for Mobile Name, RAM, Camera, Color.

Now I want to insert the data inserted by user, in these tables in such a way that entry should be done in both tables keeping in mind that `MobileID` from `MobileDetails` is a foreign key referencing `MobileID` in the `MobileMaster` table, and `MobileID` and `MobDetailsID` are kept as `Identity` (auto-increment).

So help me to do this using SQL Server as database and .net as application development platform. I am not able to write query for it which will be executed when user clicks on the `Save` button.

Comment: How are you currently interacting with the database? Entity Framework? PetaPoco? Raw ADO.NET? Something else?

Comment: What have you written so far ? Please share the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Learn about transactions.

Comment: Raw ADO.Net @mjwills